# I want to Fetch Pcr1 and Pcr2 in table body using react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to fetch a pcr1 and 2 in table body I tried but was not able to fetch the data please help
New to React, I'm currently trying to create a data table with data from an API. I want to run
pcr1 first in my table and then run another with the pcr2 response table.

Here My Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import ColumnResizer from "column-resizer";
    import "./table.css"
    import axios from "axios";
    
    
    
    
    // https://api.github.com/users
    // http://localhost:8080/AmpRestAPI/webresources/getPCRList/all
    class ReactTable extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.tableSelector = "#somethingUnique";
        this.state = {
          api: []
        }
    
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        // fetch('https://api.github.com/users').then(res => res.json().then(result => {
        //   console.log(result); this.setState({ api: result });
        // }))
    
        axios.get('/AmpRestAPI/webresources/getPCRList/all',
          {
            headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            auth: {
              username: 
              password: 
            }
          }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({ api: response.data.results });
    
          }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
          });
    
        if (this.props.resizable) {
          this.enableResize();
        }
      }
    
      componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.props.resizable) {
          this.disableResize();
        }
      }
    
      componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.resizable) {
          this.enableResize();
    
        }
      }
    
      componentWillUpdate() {
        if (this.props.resizable) {
          this.disableResize();
        }
      }
    
      enableResize() {
        const options = this.props.resizerOptions;
        if (!this.resizer) {
          this.resizer = new ColumnResizer(
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).querySelector(`${this.tableSelector}`),
            options
    
          );
        } else {
          this.resizer.reset(options);
        }
      }
    
      disableResize() {
        if (this.resizer) {
          this.resizer.reset({ disable: true });
        }
      }
    
    
    
      render() {
    
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="container-fluid  example pt-3" >
    
              <table id="somethingUnique" cellSpacing="0" className="border-primary" style={{ fontSize: "100%" }}>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="50"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                    >Thumbnail</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th ><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="0"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                    >Clip Name</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="50"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                      fill="black"
                    >Slog Name</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="20"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                      fill="black"
                    >Channel Name</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="50"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                      fill="black"
                    >Status</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="50"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                      fill="black"
                    >Loop</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="50"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                      fill="black"
                    >Start Time</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="50"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                      fill="black"
                    >Duration</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="35"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                      fill="black"
                    >Down Counter</text>
                    </svg></th>
                    <th><svg
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      viewBox="0 0 500 75"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
                    ><text
                      x="50"
                      y="75%"
                      fontSize="75"
                      fill="black"
                    >Up Counter</text>
                    </svg></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  { this.state.api ?
                    this.state.api.map(item => {
                      
                       
                      }) : null
                  }
                </tbody>
    
              </table>
    
            </div >
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default ReactTable;
```

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4EX9.png)

How can I do that nested fetch request?

Thanks a lot, How can I do that nested fetch request?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I see only one table and one call to the API (`/AmpRestAPI/webresources/getPCRList/all`)

Comment: {
    "PCR2": [
        {
            "LoadedClip": "Clip0",
            "ThumnailType": "jpeg",
            "StartTime": ":00:00"
           } ]                                                                                                                                                 "PCR1": [
        {
            "LoadedClip": "Clip0",
            "ThumnailType": "jpeg",
            "StartTime": "00:00",
            "Duration": "10:04"} ]  }                                                                                                i want to display this data api in table

Comment: I see. But in your code you set the state variable `api` as `response.data.results` while in the JSON there is no `results`. There are `RPC1` and `RPC1`. Anyway, if you want to concat them into one array to populate the table, you can using spread, like this `this.setState({api: [...response.data.RPC1, ...response.data.RPC2]})`

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure. Is it solved your issue?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear :)